# Uncaught ReferenceError: showimg is not defined

Tags: javascript

As the title says, the console is telling me that the function `showimg` is not defined.. But I believe it is defined.. (I havent used Javascript in a while, so it might be something obvious)

The code:

```
let links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
let url = 'https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=64x64&data=';
let hiddenNode = null;
//let shifting = true;

for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  let linkNode = links.item(i);
  let link = linkNode.href;

  let img = document.createElement("img");
  img.setAttribute("src", url + link);
  img.setAttribute('height', '128');
  img.setAttribute('width', '128');

  linkNode.setAttribute('onmouseover', 'showimg(this, img)');
  img.setAttribute('onmmouseout', 'hideimg(this)');

}

function showimg(node, imgtoshow) {
  //if (shifting) {
  hiddenNode = node;
  node.parentNode.replaceChild(imgtoshow, node);
  //}
}

function hideimg(theimg) {
  theimg.parentNode.replaceChild(hiddenNode, img);
}


/*function onKeyDown() {
  shifting = (key == 'shift');
}

function onKeyUp() {
  if (key == 'shift') {
    shifting = false;
  }
}*/
```

Comment: Why are you using attributes instead of event listeners?

Comment: May be change `linkNode.setAttribute('onmouseover', 'showimg(this, img)');` to `linkNode.setAttribute('onmouseover', showimg(this, img));`

Because u defined it as a function but you are sending as string in the setAttribute

Comment: Do not use strings of code (which know nothing about scope), and don't use `setAttribute` to create an inline event listener. Use `linkNode.onmouseOver = function(e) { showimg(this, img); }` instead (same for `img.onmousout`).

Comment: Ok thanks for your help everyone :) I seem to have solved the problem by using event listeners instead of the attrubutes like Luca Kiebel suggested :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by using eventlisteners instead of the html attributes, as Luca Kiebel suggested